# Erro na inserção de dados no postgree: column "teste" does not exist

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql

Em um `crud` básico, estou recebendo o seguinte erro do node:

> ```
> "Erro na inserção dos dados { error: column "teste" does not exist
>     at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\SUPORTE\Desktop\NodeFINAL\appFinal\app1\nod
> modules\pg\lib\connection.js:546:11)
>     at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\SUPORTE\Desktop\NodeFINAL\appFinal\ap
> \node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:371:19)
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SUPORTE\Desktop\NodeFINAL\appFinal\app1\no
> _modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:22)
>     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
>     at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
>   name: 'error',
>   length: 117,
>   severity: 'ERROR',
>   code: '42703',
>   detail: undefined,
>   hint: undefined,
>   position: '48',
>   internalPosition: undefined,
>   internalQuery: undefined,
>   where: undefined,
>   schema: undefined,
>   table: undefined,
>   column: undefined,
>   dataType: undefined,
>   constraint: undefined,
>   file: 'src\\backend\\parser\\parse_relation.c',
>   line: '2985',
>   routine: 'errorMissingColumn' }"
> ```

Minha rota:

```
app.post('/insere', function (req, res){
// conecta no banco a partir do canal
canal.connect(function(erro, conexao, feito){
    if (erro){ // ocorreu um erro
        return console.error('erro ao conectar no banco', erro);
    }
    var sql = 'insert into fornecedores values (' + req.body.codigo + 
              ',\'' + req.body.nome + 
              '\', '+ req.body.idade + 
              ',' + req.body.produto + ')';
    conexao.query(sql, function(erro, resultado){
        feito(); // libera a conexão
        if (erro){
            return console.error('Erro na inserção dos dados', erro);
        }
        res.json(resultado.rows); // retorna ao cliente o resultado da inserção
    });
});
```

});

Meu modelo no html:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2"> Produto </label>
                <div class="col-sm-6"> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="fornecedor.produto"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Acontece que eu preencho na `label` "Produto" o `valor`: "teste" ou qualquer outro valor, e o node retorna aquela mensagem que a `column` não existe.

No meu banco de dados (`postgree`) foi criado a tabela `fornecedores` e os campos: `codigo`, `nome`, `idade` e `produto`.

Comment: Talvez esteja faltando aspas no `req.body.produto` ?

Comment: de um console.log(sql) e post o resultado.

Comment: @CassioAlves retornou: insert into fornecedores values (1,'teste', 22,teste)

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no seu comentário, basta colocar o nome do produto entre aspas:

```
var sql = 'insert into fornecedores values (' + req.body.codigo + 
                                            ',\'' + req.body.nome + 
                                            '\', '+ req.body.idade + 
                                            ',\'' + req.body.produto + '\')';
```